# How to parse string in swift

Tags: json, swift, string, dictionary

My json is like this:

```
"billerdetails": [
{
"id": "1",
"bname": "ACT Fibernet",
"bcustomerparms": "[{\"paramName\":\"Account Number/User Name\",\"dataType\":\"ALPHANUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"1\",\"maxLength\":\"50\"}]",
"breponseParams": "[{\"amtBreakupList\":[{\"amtBreakup\":\"BASE_BILL_AMOUNT\"}]}]",
......
```

Here i am able to get `bcustomerparms`. but here i need bcustomerparms: `paramName` value like (Account Number/User Name) in one virable.. for that i have written code like below but i am unable to get Account Number/User Name in vairable.

Please help me in below code:

```
do{
let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
//print("the all make payment json is \(jsonObj)")

let billerdetailsArray = jsonObj["billerdetails"] as! [[String: Any]]

for billerdetail in billerdetailsArray {

    self.categoryName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
    var customrParams = billerdetail["bcustomerparms"]
    print("biller customrParams \(customrParams)") 
 }
```

// here i am getting bcustomerparms

> biller customrParams Optional([{"paramName":"Connection ID","dataType":"ALPHANUMERIC","optional":"false","minLength":"8","maxLength":"10"}])

but here i want only paramName value how to get that value. please help me in the above code.

Comment: means you want only "paramName"  in customrParams?

Comment: @SGDev yes only paramName value like Connection ID in one variable..

Comment: Are you responsible for the JSON? If yes don't send nested JSON (another JSON string as a dictionary value), that's pretty bad practice.

Comment: @vadian, no, i am getting JSON from backend team

Comment: Then ask the backend team to send more reasonable JSON (and more consistent key names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bcustomerparms` value is a string not an array of dictionaries , You can try

```
let customrParams = billerdetail["bcustomerparms"] as! String
let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(customrParams.utf8)) as! [[String: Any]]
for item in res {
  print(item["paramName"])
}
```

Comment: I have tried ur answer, it is working, i have accepted ur answer, but i need some more help to send that paramName to nextVC using didSelectRowAt indexPath

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I am able to do remaining work, upvote for you!!

Comment: please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928204/how-to-send-selected-item-all-paramname-values-to-next-view-controller-while-par?noredirect=1#comment104116753_58928204